# Fetch twitter json data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to track twitter account in a spreadsheet. Want to track total-follower, total-tweets, total-likes & daily engagement. So I've written script using `Google Apps Script`. The json data is exist on attribute named `value` of  tag. I've written a script but it gives an error message. Please help me with your valuable suggestion.

I've written function for this project.

```
function insertData(sheetName, twitterAccountName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  accountdata = getTwitterData(twitterAccountName);
sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd"),twitterAccountName, accountdata.followerCount, accountdata.followCount,accountdata.totalComments, accountdata.totalLikes, accountdata.EngagementRatio]);
};
function getTwitterData(username) {
  var r = new RegExp('<input type="hidden" id="init-data"' + 
                     '([^{]+?({.*tweetContextEnabled.*})[^}]+?)' +
                     'false}}">');
  var url = "https://twitter.com/" + username, totalComments = 0, totalLikes = 0;
  var ignoreError = {
   "muteHttpExcecptions":true
  };
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var jsonStr = source.match(r)[2];
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
  console.log('data', data);

  return {
    followerCount : data.profile_user.followers_count,
    followCount : data.profile_user.friends_count, 
    totalComments : data.profile_user.statuses_count,
    totalLikes : data.profile_user.favourites_count,
  }  
}
```

Given error message

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token in object literal (line 29, file "Code")

Comment: Which line is "line 29" ?

Comment: 'Line 29' is : ```var data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);```

Comment: Have you captured the value of "jsonStr" and checked it on JSONLint (or similar) to see if it is valid json?

Comment: If nothing else, the line previous to that is pretty dangerous - you assume that there will be an array with at least three members, but don't do anything to test that assumption!

Answer (score 0):

I found two issues:

1) `jsonStr` had all `"` characters encoded as `&quot;`.  That is what's causing your error message.  You need to fix that; I used the `String.prototype.replace` method below.

2) The regular expression was not returning the complete JSON.  I just removed the `false}}` bit.

This is working for me.

```js
function getTwitterData(username) {
  var r = new RegExp('<input type="hidden" id="init-data"' + 
                     '([^{]+?({.*tweetContextEnabled.*})[^}]+?)">');
  var url = "https://twitter.com/" + username;
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var jsonStr = source.match(r)[2].replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

  return {
    followerCount : data.profile_user.followers_count,
    followCount : data.profile_user.friends_count, 
    totalComments : data.profile_user.statuses_count,
    totalLikes : data.profile_user.favourites_count,
  }  
}
```